# No funciona correctamente slice JS, por que?

Tags: php, javascript

la funcion slice devuelve un array con los valores desde el indice inicio hasta el indice final, tengo un arrayproducts que es resultado de toda la tabla finished products de mi bd, en total son 17 filas, por lo que arrayproducts tiene longitud 17, ahora yo quiero devolver los datos de 5 en 5 para no tener que imprimirlos todos de una, por lo que uso la funcion slice quedando asi:

```
arrayproducts = response.data //este array tiene longitud 17
    
//creo un nuevo array

listproducts = arrayproducts.slice(0,5);
console.log(listproducts);
```

aqui funciona bien, me devuelve los 5 objetos, pero a la hora de buscar los proximos 5 me devuelve un array vacio, cuando todavia tiene longitud, quedando:

```
listproducts = arrayproducts(6,10);
console.log(listproducts) //aqui me devuelve el array vacio.
```

por que pasa esto?, lo probe en w3schools el mismo ejemplo y alla funciona, siendo:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to extract the second and the third elements from the array.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<p id="demo2"></p>

<p id="demo3"></p>

<p id="demo4"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Lemon", "Apple", "Mango"];
  var citrus = fruits.slice(0, 2);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = citrus;
   var citrus = fruits.slice(2, 4);
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = citrus;
var citrus = fruits.slice(4, 6);
document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = citrus;

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

asi esta mi codigo:

```
        this.productsarray = this.productsarray.slice(5,10);
        console.log(this.productsarray);
        this.productsarray = this.productsarray.slice(10,15);
        console.log(this.productsarray);
        this.productsarray = this.productsarray.slice(15,20);
        console.log(this.productsarray);
```

Comment: Tienes un error aquí: `listproducts = arrayproducts(6,10);`, debe ser: `listproducts = arrayproducts.slice(6,10);` Verifica eso. Saludos

Comment: De acuerdo con @MauricioContreras, además `slice(0,5)` te devolvería los elemntos 1,2,3 y 4. El principio y el final no los devuelve. Salu3

Comment: perdon amigo, error de tipeo xD, lo tengo asi en el codigo y aun asi no funciona

Comment: editada mi publicacion para que vean mejor

Comment: @gabrielcoronel, tienes un error. Sí que devuelve el primer elemento, el que no devuelve es el último. Hacer uso de `slice(0,5)` devuelve desde el elemento 0 al 4, y hacer uso de  `slice(6, 10)` devuelve los elementos desde el 6 al 9. Cualquier duda, consultar la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/slice). Saludos

Comment: @plus en tu edición se ve que estás **modificando** el array. Por eso después de aplicar el primer `slice`, tu array ya no tiene todos los elementos, tiene sólo los primeros 5. Debes usar otra variable para almacenar el array original y hacer uso del método sin alterarla. Saludos